# Scanner carriage return Overflow

Tags: java, loops, runtime-error, java.util.scanner, stack-overflow

If anyone can see where I've gone made a mistake in my code I would be eternally grateful. I recognize that it's an obscene amount of code, but I've been pulling my hair out with it over the last few days and simply cannot fathom what to do with it. I've asked others for help in my class but they cannot see where I have gone wrong. It's to do with carriage return scanner problem.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at PropertyMenu.runMenu(PropertyMenu.java:109)
    at PropertyMenu.main(PropertyMenu.java:7)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
```

edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Joe.

//ROOM CLASS

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Room{

  private String description;
  private double length;
  private double width;

  public Room (String description, double length, double width) {
    this.description = description;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;     
   }
  public Room(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useDelimiter("\n");

    System.out.println("Enter description of room:");
    description = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Enter length of room:");
    length = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter width of room:");
    width = scan.nextDouble();
   }

   public double getArea () {
     return length*width;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     String result = ("***********************************\n");
            result +=("            Room Viewing            \n");
            result +=("************************************\n");
            result +=("The width of the room is " + width + "m.\n");
            result +=("the length of the room is " + length + "m.\n");
            result +=("the name of the room is: " + description +".\n");
     return result;
   }   
}
```

//HOUSE CLASS

```
import java.util.*;
public class House {
  private ArrayList<Room> abode;
  private int idNum, numRooms;
  private double totalArea;
  private static int internalCount = 1;
  private String address, roomInfo, houseType;

  public House (String address, String houseType, int numRooms){
    System.out.println("THIS IS THE START OF MY 3 ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR");
    idNum = internalCount++;
    this.address = address;
    this.houseType = houseType; 
    this.numRooms = numRooms;
    System.out.println("THIS IS THE END OF MY 3 ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR");
  }
  public House (String address, String houseType, int numRooms,  String roomInfo){
    System.out.println("THIS IS THE START OF MY 4 ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR");
    idNum = internalCount++;
    this.address = address;
    this.houseType = houseType; 
    this.numRooms = numRooms;
    this.roomInfo = roomInfo;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(roomInfo);

    String desc;
    Double l;
    Double w;

    while (scan.hasNext()){
    desc= scan.next();
    l = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
    System.out.println("the length from here"+l);
    w = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
    System.out.println("the width from here"+w);

    new Room (desc,l,w);
    }
    System.out.println("THIS IS THE END OF MY 4 ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR");
  }
  public void addRoom (){
     totalArea=0;
     abode.add(new Room ());
     for (int i=0; i<abode.size(); i++){
       totalArea += abode.get(i).getArea();
     }
   }
  public House () {
    totalArea = 0;
    abode = new ArrayList<Room>();
    idNum = ++internalCount;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useDelimiter("\n");

    System.out.println("Enter address of house:");
    address = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Enter number of rooms:");
    numRooms = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter type of house:");
    houseType = scan.next();

    for (int i=1; i<=numRooms; i++){
      addRoom();
    }
  }
  int getIdNum() {
    return idNum;
  }

    @Override
   public String toString() {
      String result =("************************************\n");
            result +=("            House Viewing           \n");
            result +=("************************************\n");
            result +=("The house ID is " + idNum +".\n");
            result +=("The house address is " + address +".\n");
            result +=("The number of rooms here is " + numRooms +".\n");
            result +=("The house type is " + houseType +".\n");
            result +=("The total area of the house is " + totalArea +".\n");
            result +=(abode);
     return result;
   }   
}
```

//DRIVER

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class PropertyMenu {
  private ArrayList<House> properties =new ArrayList<House>();
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
    PropertyMenu menu = new PropertyMenu();
    menu.runMenu();
  }

  public void runMenu() {

    House h = null;
    char selection = ' ';
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (selection != 'e') {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("Welcome to my Property database");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("To ADD a house enter......A");
    System.out.println("To VIEW a house enter.....V");
    System.out.println("To DELETE a house enter...D");
    System.out.println("To USE a file.............F");
    System.out.println("To QUIT enter.............E");
    selection = s.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

      switch (selection) {
        case 'a':
          properties.add(new House());
          break;
        case 'v':
          System.out.println("Do you want to view all houses (y/n)?");
          String all = "";
          all = s.next();

          if (all.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            for (int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++){
              System.out.println("Property ID: "+ (properties.get(i)));
            }
          }
          else if(all.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            System.out.println(""+ properties.size() +" houses have been created, choose the id of the house you wish to view.. (1/2/3 etc...)");
            System.out.println("List of property ID's: ");  
            for (int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++){
              System.out.println("Property ID: "+ (properties.get(i)).getIdNum());
            }
            System.out.println("Enter ID of the house you wish to view:");
            int viewHouse = s.nextInt();
            if (viewHouse <= properties.size() && viewHouse >= 1){
              System.out.println(properties.get(viewHouse-1));
            }
            else{
              System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
              System.out.println("       House Not Present       ");
              System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            }
          }
          else{
            System.out.println("Do you want to view all houses (y/n)?");
            all = s.next();
          }
          break;
        case 'd':
          System.out.println(""+ properties.size() +" houses have been created, choose the id of the house you wish to delete.. (1/2/3 etc...)");
          System.out.println("List of property ID's: ");  
          for (int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Property ID: "+ (properties.get(i)).getIdNum());
          }
          System.out.println("Enter ID of the house you wish to delete:");
          int deleteHouse = s.nextInt();
          if (deleteHouse <= properties.size() && deleteHouse >= 1){
            properties.remove(deleteHouse -1);
          }
          else{
            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            System.out.println("       House Not Present       ");
            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
          }
          break;
        case 'e':
          System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
          System.out.println("         Goodbye               ");
          System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
          break;

//*********************************THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS, FROM HERE*************

        case 'f':
          try{
          Scanner fileScan = new Scanner (new File("property.txt"));
          while (fileScan.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("THIS IS A FRESH LOOP");

            String a;
            String ht;
            String rms1;
            int rms;
            String yn;
            String rmInfo;

            a = fileScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("ADDRESS"+a);
            ht = fileScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("HOUSE TYPE"+ht);
            rms1 = fileScan.next();
            rms = Integer.parseInt(rms1);
            System.out.println("HOUSEROOMs"+rms);
            yn = fileScan.next();
            String overflow = fileScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Yes/no"+yn);

            if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
              System.out.println("THIS IS THE START OF CHOICE = Y");
              rmInfo = fileScan.nextLine();
              properties.add(new House(a, ht, rms, rmInfo));
              System.out.println("THIS IS THE END OF CHOICE = Y");
            }
            else{
              System.out.println("THIS IS THE START OF CHOICE = N");
              properties.add(new House(a, ht, rms));
              System.out.println("THIS IS THE END OF CHOICE = N");
            }

          }
        }
          catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          break;

//******************************************TO HERE^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        default:
          System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
          System.out.println("         Try again!            ");
          System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
      }
    }
      System.out.println("Exiting program.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the problem occur?

Comment: More details on what to do to reproduce the problem, and what exactly the problem is, will help us help you.

Comment: Ah, if one scrolls down about 2/3 of the way in the `PropertyMenu` class (the third code block, below "//DRIVER"), there are comments delimiting the section where the error occurs (but not what exactly it is).

Comment: Can you show us the structure of `property.txt`. It looks like you have problen while reading file.

Comment: Apologies, this is property.txt https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByjHjAVxgVWCN05wZkMyTXdZeTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JoeAustin What is the the program supposed to do? I mean how the way you want to read this file?

Comment: I get a runtime error that occurs after the last property has been accepted to the 'properties' ArrayList.

Comment: The program is supposed to read a text file using scanner to create House objects (which in return creates room objects) in an Array List.

Comment: @JoeAustin What is the error? Please edit that in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is could be a guess that you are not reading file correctly. Whatever I see from your block of file reading code and input file "property.txt" , make following changes.

1. In your while use following, as you are reading file line by line.

   ```
   while (fileScan.hasNextLine()){
   ```
2. Only use nextLine() method

   ```
   rms1 = fileScan.nextLine();
   yn = fileScan.nextLine();
   ```

I hope these will solve your problem.